# Getting the time of the received message

Tags: erlang

How does one get the time of the received message in Erlang?

I want to calculate something according to the frequency of the received messages to the gen_server.

e.g. message 1, some time, message 2 some time.
get the time between messages.

Thanks

Comment: yes. One for the total up/down speed for the torrent and then also for the peer choking, individual peer rate calculation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`statistics(wall_clock)`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#statistics-1) each time you receive a message.
The second member of the tuple it returns will be the time between the two receives (in milliseconds).

**Edit**:

As rvirding mentions in his comment, you can also use [`now()`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#now-0) and then calculate the time difference accordingly. Take a look at `supervisor.erl` found in the `$ERL_TOP/lib/stdlib/src/` directory of your Erlang/OTP distribution. The last lines of that module (functions `addRestart`, `inPeriod` and `difference`) calculate the frequency of restarts using `now()`.

Comment: Or, to be more precise, the time between two calls to `statistics(wall_clock)`. An alternative is to use `now()` which returns microsecond resolution.