# Message receive rate for an Erlang process

Tags: erlang

Is there a counter in Erlang VM for received messages per process?
I need to calculate message rate for a worker.

If not, how would you measure and calculate message rate in your code?

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```
erlang:process_info(Pid, message_queue_len)
```

The result you will get something like:

```
{message_queue_len, Number}
```

but maybe this is not what you are looking for.

If you are using OTP you can use observer as @Pascal said, or you can keep a counter in the state and update it every time you handle a call, info or cast.

Comment: If throughput is high, long message queue is okey. I'm trying to figure out how long a message stays in the queue.

Comment: then i believe this could be useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4281251/getting-the-time-of-the-received-message

Answer (score 2):

If your process is fully OTP compliant (for instance, a gen_server, gen_event, gen_fsm) you can use [`sys:statistics/2,3`](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/sys.html#statistics-2) to trace the messages_in/messages_out rate. From what I gather from the documentation, you call it with Flag = true, wait for a period of time, and then call it again with Flag = get (not sure if you then have to call it again with Flag = false).

That being said, it's relatively easy to do without OTP compliance. Set a timer up (I recommend `erlang:start_timer` over the timer module) to fire a message to your process after N milliseconds, and count the number of messages you receive. When you receive the message from the timer, divide the count by N for a rate-per-millisecond (multiply by 1000 for rate-per-second). Rinse and repeat.

This gets a little tedious if you're doing this, say, from a callback module, or with a receive-block based process that handles a wide variety of messages (in which case you should convert it to a callback form anyway), so I don't exactly recommend it. So if you're working with an OTP process, use the sys module for the sake of your sanity.

Answer (score 0):

If you have built an OTP application, then i guess you can use the observer application.

Simply run observer:start() in a VM executing an OTP application to have a look.